# How to define default views in Plone

Tags: plone

I have already a page template for the default view of a Plone site (main page).
How to define the default view of a folder? This default view should use a page template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

- navigate to the desired folder
- add "/manage_propertiesForm" at the end of the url
- in the resulting form add this property:

  - *name*: "layout"
  - *type*: "string"
  - *value*: the page template name without extension

Comment: Ciao Giacomo! Grazie mille pela tua riposta. Is it possible to make this modification via Python?

Comment: Yes it is: `folder.manage_addProperty('layout','*templatename*','string')`

Comment: Grazie! Another question: is is possible to do this in a configuration file/folder? Like, for example, the structure folder with the .properties file?

Comment: No there isn't that feature out-of-the-box but it won't be too difficult to implement.

Comment: Could you please, point me to some resource where this implementation would be explained? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Terve Mikko! Kiitos for the answer. I'll check it and see if I can make it work.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa's link updated: http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/content/dynamic_views.html

Answer (score 6):

Use the answers above if you want to set one of the default views (tabular, thumbnail, etc), but if you want to choose a particular content item for the default view of the folder, you can do it in the ZMI as suggested:

- navigate to the desired folder
- add "/manage_propertiesForm" at the end of the url
- in the resulting form add this property:

  - name: "default_page"
  - type: "string"
  - value: the id of the content item

or do it programmatically in Python:

```
content_id = "Name of the Content Item"
folder.manage_addProperty('default_page', content_id, 'string')
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Using the information and links send both by Giacomo Spettoli and by Mikko Ohtamaa, another guy from my work team was able to find a solution for our case:

- do as indicated by Giacomo (navigate to desired folder, etc.)
- include a new directive in the configure.zcml file (this was found by on of my team mate Mr. Mariano):

  ```
  <browser:page for="OFS.interfaces.IFolder" name=<name of the page template file> class=<name of the class used by the above template file> permission="zope2.View" />
  ```

Thanks to Giacomo and to Mikko; their answers helped us solve this issue.