# How would one set the default view of content that is imported via Generic Setup (structure)

Tags: plone, genericsetup

I already know how to programatically set the default view content, in my specific case, a Folder, or how to use the Plone UI to do it.  In my case, I am creating a large skeleton of content via GenericSetup and I need a set of folders to have a specific content item in each folder be the default view.

So, I have a folder structure like so:

```
folder1/
-- .properties
-- page1
-- homepage1
folder2/
-- .properties
-- page2
-- homepage2
```

I would think that in:

```
profile/default/structure/folder1/.properties
```

you would be able to add:

```
DefaultView = homepage1
```

or similar.  So the question is: "Is it possible to set the default view of a content item using Generic Setup?"

This answer might also work; I haven't tried it yet because I'd like some feedback on my question before moving away from GS to using ZCML.

[How to define default views in Plone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914479/how-to-define-default-views-in-plone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GS structure importer doesn't support this; it has no idea about the (Plone specific) Dynamic Layout support.

You'll have to write your own custom GS step to do this, I am afraid, or perhaps use something like [plone.app.transmogrifier](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.transmogrifier) (it includes support for browser defaults and [collective.transmogrifier](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.transmogrifier) includes a GS step) to configure this.

Comment: ok thank you, I'll add it to my list of "features to add someday" ;-)

Comment: Get some inspiration from Products.CMFPlone, look for the setLayout() method: https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/setuphandlers.py#L264